# Trying to retrain a tensorflow model, input and output nodes disappear

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to retrain the tensorflow deeplab model using MobileNet_V2. I have downloaded the checkpoint from the deeplab model zoo, about halfway down this page:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md
Specifically, the [mobilenetv2_coco_voc_trainaug](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_train_aug_2018_01_29.tar.gz) one. I would like my retrained output to have the same graph, but different parameters as this one. (Well, almost the same graph, the final tensor should probably have a different shape because I am trying to work with a different number of classes.)

I assembled my own images into a tfrecord, labelled with just one class for now. This is practice for a dataset with 4 classes.

I then ran the following to retrain the network, producing `.pbtxt`, `.meta`, `.index` and `.data-00000-of-00001` files:

```
PATH_TO_INITIAL_CHECKPOINT=/path/to/unzipped/files/model.ckpt-30000.index
PATH_TO_TRAIN_DIR=/path/to/checkpoints/
PATH_TO_DATASET=/path/to/tfrecord
python /path/to/tensorflow/models/research/deeplab/train.py \
    --logtostderr \
    --training_number_of_steps=900 \ # 90000 \
    --train_split="train" \
    --model_variant="mobilenet_v2" \
    --output_stride=16 \
    --decoder_output_stride=4 \
    --train_crop_size=128 \
    --train_crop_size=128 \
    --train_batch_size=1 \
    --dataset="cityscapes" \
    --tf_initial_checkpoint=${PATH_TO_INITIAL_CHECKPOINT} \
    --train_logdir=${PATH_TO_TRAIN_DIR} \
    --dataset_dir=${PATH_TO_DATASET} \
    --initialize_last_layer=False \
    --last_layers_contain_logits_only=True \
    --fine_tune_batch_norm=False
```

Running bazel's summarize_graph on the downloaded file gives:

```
Found 1 possible inputs: (name=ImageTensor, type=uint8(4), shape=[1,?,?,3]) 
No variables spotted.
Found 1 possible outputs: (name=SemanticPredictions, op=Slice)
```

When I scan the nodes of the `.pbtxt` file, I can't find any nodes called ImageTensor or SemanticPredictions. I have tried with tensorboard, bazel's summarize_graph, and programmatically (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066621/how-to-find-the-output-node-names-for-a-specific-tensorflow-network), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017356), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51811464/1295595)). Summarize_graph says `No inputs spotted` and `Found 664 possible outputs:`.

This then leads to problems with `freeze_graph.py`. If I choose `output_node_names` from what I can see on tensorbord, then `freeze_graph.py` runs, and I am able to get a frozen graph. But running that model gives me

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 
'ImageTensor:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 
'ImageTensor', does not exist in the graph.
```

I'm definitely doing something wrong here. The question is: what? I suspect it could be the arguments I supply to train.py, but really, that's just a shot in the dark. It could be that this is not how `train.py` is intended to be used, or deeplab's `train.py` is not compatible with MobileNetV2.

Edit: After a closer look at the options available in train.py, I have updated my command. Cleaning previous failed models from the TRAIN_DIR was also helpful to avoid the error:

```
Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch 
between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure 
that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint.
```

Comment: I did put a bounty on this question, but it has expired. If anyone manages to come up with an answer, I'd be happy to put the bounty up again. (Related question: how come the bounty isn't returned to me when it expires? I guess you wouldn't want people to offer a bounty and then keep it for themselves, but since there were no answers, that doesn't really apply here.)

Comment: oh. "All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances." Apparently it's intended to be more comparable to advertising than a reward. https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty